# Are "excerpt" and "excerption" interchangeable?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

Can *excerpt* and *excerption* replace each other in a particular sentence without changing its meaning? For example, given these two sentences:

> 1. He presented **excerpts** from William James' philosophical writings.
> 2. He presented **excerptions** from William James' philosophical writings.

Do both these nouns give the same meaning or change the sense in any way? Or is either of these two sentences wrong?

Comment: Don't know if it's wrong, but the second would be very uncommon and a lot of people would probably think you were mixing up "excerpts" and "exceptions"

Answer (score 5):

According to the OED, *excerption* refers to the act of taking an *excerpt*, so it's kind of a "meta" word. Sentence 2 above would be strange in that context. The use of *excerption* to mean *an extract* or *an excerpt* is archaic.

Answer (score 1):

They do not seem to be same but both are nouns. Excerpt means *a shorter text selected from a larger text*. Excerption means *the act of taking an excerpt*.

However,

http://www.audioenglish.net/dictionary/excerpt.htm and

http://www.audioenglish.net/dictionary/excerption.htm

suggest that both may mean the same but excerption is very rarely used. It seems you picked your examples from here.